# Left of a character in a string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

say if I have a string **010451-09F2**

How to I get left of - from the above string in vb.net

I want **010451**

The left function doesn't allow me to specify seperator character.

Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Given:

```
Dim strOrig = "010451-09F2"
```

You can do any of the following:

```
Dim leftString = strOrig.Substring(0, strOrig.IndexOf("-"))
```

Or:

```
Dim leftString = strOrig.Split("-"c)(0) ' Take the first index in the array
```

Or:

```
Dim leftString = Left(strOrig, InStr(strOrig, "-"))
' Could also be: Mid(strOrig, 0, InStr(strOrig, "-"))
```

Comment: Add Mid/Left with InStr, remove the ugly Split, and this answer is complete.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if the string doesn't contain a "-" the Substring...IndexOf will throw an ArgumentOutOfRange exception, but the Split method just returns the whole string.

Comment: @AMissico: Added them for completeness  ;)

Comment: Dear Readers: Be aware that Left will conflict with Form's Left property, so you may need to qualify it.

Comment: @AMissico: Yes - that's potentially true, IF this is being used in a Windows Forms project, inside of a Form's code.  If not, then it's not an issue.

Answer (score 11):

```
Dim str As String = "010451-09F2"
Dim leftPart As String = str.Split("-")(0)
```

Split gives you the left and right parts in a string array. Accessing the first element (index 0) gives you the left part.

Comment: You mean get rid of the Char data type declaration by removing the c.

Comment: It's not an error. It's used to indicate that "-" is a character and not a string. (equivalent to '-' in C#)

Comment: @JL, it is not an error because Split allows "ByVal ParamArray separator() As Char".

Comment: @AMissico: JL is a C# programmer that doesn't know VB's syntax. I didn't know taht you defined a char that way in that language and too thought it was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not sure on the vb syntax, but the c# is

```
 string mystring ="010451-09F2";
 string whatIwant = mystring.Split('-')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dim s as String = "010451-09F2"
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("-")))
Console.WriteLine(s.Split("-")(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of the dash first (or do it inline), and use that value for the left.  This is old school VBA, but it'll be something like this:

Left(YourStringWithTheDash, InStr(YourStringWithTheDash)-1)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

Mid("010451-09F2",1,InStr("-"))

Comment: This VB6 code. In VB.net you have more advanced structures that aer more readable.

Comment: It is not VB6 code. It is Visual Basic statements and it is much more readable to me then the "advanced" stuff. In general, these Visual Basic statements are more complete and robust then the equivalent .NET Framework methods.

Comment: I dont have much idea about string fundtions in VB .Net. I have used it many times but thought something like this you can find in your vb .net. Thank for your information on this.
I have used this in C#:
string s ="010451-09F2"; 
s= s.Substring(1, s.IndexOf("-")-1); and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim sValue As String = "010451-09F2"
    Debug.WriteLine(sValue.Substring(0, sValue.IndexOf("-"c)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped

```
Dim str1 as string = me@test.com
Dim str As String

str = Strings.Left(str1, str1.LastIndexOf("@"))
```