# Left split, getting blank return.

Tags: vb.net

Issue, where the character I am removing does not exist I get a blank string

Aim: To look for three characters in order and only get the characters to the left of the character I am looking for. However if the character does not exist then to do nothing.

Code:

```
Dim vleftString As String = File.Name
vleftString = Left(vleftString, InStr(vleftString, "-"))
vleftString = Left(vleftString, InStr(vleftString, "_"))
vleftString = Left(vleftString, InStr(vleftString, " "))
```

As a 'fix' I have done

```
Dim vleftString As String = File.Name
                    vleftString = Replace(vleftString, "-", " ")
                    vleftString = Replace(vleftString, "_", " ")
                    vleftString = Left(vleftString, InStr(vleftString, " "))
vleftString  = Trim(vleftString)
```

Based on [Left of a character in a string in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461025/left-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-vb-net#)

If File.Name is say 1_2.pdf it passes "-" and then works on line removing anything before "*" (though not "*" though I want it to)

When it hits the line for looking for anything left of space it then makes vleftString blank.

Comment: So, if the file name is `"1_3-2.pdf"`, do you want to get `"1_3"` or just `"1"`?

Comment: you need to test if `Instr` is -1 each time before you try to get the left string part.  If `Instr` =-1 it means the character was not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i'm not familiar (and avoid)  the old VB functions here a .NET approach. I assume you want to remove the parts behind the separators `"-"`, `"_"` and `" "`, then you can use this loop:

```
Dim fileName = "1_2.pdf".Trim() ' Trim used to show you the method, here nonsense
Dim name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Trim()
For Each separator In {"-", "_", " "}
    Dim index = name.IndexOf(separator)
    If index >= 0 Then
        name = name.Substring(0, index)
    End If
Next
fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}", name, Path.GetExtension(fileName))
```

Result: `"1.pdf"`

Comment: This works on it's own but when I put it into my code it makes the project fail but will not show an error. Is this part c# code? Thanks I have tried converting in but no joy.

Comment: @indofraiser: in what way does it fail? Have you debugged it? This is pure VB.NET. Maybe you have used a different .NET framework in your project than in your test project.

Comment: If I change the For line to the following it works which is great. Strange it worked standalone, does that imply an issue with my main code? --->  For Each separator In New Char() {"-", "_", " "}

Comment: @indofraiser: that does only imply a different framework since [Collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) were introduced in VS 2010 (.NET 4). Before you need to specify the type explicitly as you've done above. It was just an example, i would initialize the array before the loop.

Comment: That'll be it. Going onto a 'non-standard' server compared to the others. So long as there is a reason. :-) Thank you for the initial and additional help. I'll get reading.