# How do I read an ":" Parameter of a String until it hits a NUL

Tags: vb.net, file, mesh

(Not sure if I'm on the right part of the website, so sorry if I ain't, and feel free to close the thread then, but at least redirect me to the right site)

The title might be a little confusing, but here's what I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to make an Tool which generates "GUI-Mapping" Files for a game called Star Wolves 3, it works well when in Manual-Edit-Mode but I am also trying to make an Automatic mode, where the program scans one of the Game's 3D-Mesh files (.IMD) and searches for a string like this "Turret:1", it does not necessarily has to be a number, a string could also be behind the ":".

Now what I want is, to basically Read everything behind the ":" until it hits a NUL, here's what I mean by that by showing you a picture of a generic .IMD file and the ":" Parameter of the String "Turret"
[Picture](http://oi59.tinypic.com/69185w.jpg).

I'm pretty bad at .NET and could really take a hint or two to solve this problem. I have honestly no actual Idea on what Code I need write to get whats behind the ":" and stop reading the text until it hits the NUL, sample code might also be very helpful.

Any help is appreciated!

.. although there is a non-opensource tool by someone else which can read these "Parameters" flawlessly called "IMD Editor_v3", the developer "tech" vanished and there's no way for me to contact that developer and/or ask for help.

Comment: If you already have the file contents as a string, then you can use [the `Substring` member of `String`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461025/left-of-a-character-in-a-string-in-vb-net)

Comment: `Substring` combined with `IndexOf` to find where in the string to get the substring. IndexOf `:`

Comment: Great!, there has been a bit of Progress over at my side, thanks to your help I can get the first Turret's Parameter, but now I need to do the same trick for Multiple occurances in the same file, any Ideas?.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, then you should post the solution as an Answer to your own question, rather than as an edit to the question. I've rolled back your question to the original.